# fullcalendar enable the user to add end time when event created

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker, fullcalendar

Is it possible to enable the user to enter or select the start and end time of an event. At the moment it seems it's defaulting to 1 hour however i would like the user to be able to define events for 10mins or more?

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Can you detail what are you trying to accomplish? If you want the user to be able to create events in 10-min time slots, you could use [snapDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/snapDuration/). [check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/o95mxuvj/).

Comment: hi Milz. Thanks. ! This is kinda getting there however i was hoping to enable the user to enter the details themselfs at event entry level rather than through thr drag. I suppose this question coulf evolve into how can i use a form instead of the default popup to collect the appointment information.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two options, depending on how you want your users to create events.

1. **Users create events with a simple drag and drop**

Make use of [`snapDuration`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/snapDuration/), so that users are able to select 10-min time slots. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/o95mxuvj/).

2. **Users create events based on a form** (either the form is always present or it is displayed after drag and drop)

My solution uses a form inside a modal dialog that is displayed after the user has selected a timeslot. However, you can simply remove the modal dialog altogether and always display the form.

The basic process is:

- Show the modal after the user has selected a timeslot. Use [`select`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) to accomplish this.
- Before we show the dialog, set the event start and event end values, based on what the user has selected.
- Show the modal dialog.
- Bind the [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event of the form, in order to perform a ajax call when the form is submitted. This ajax call will save the event into the database and, when it is saved successfully, close the dialog and refresh the calendar.

You function will be something like this:

```
select: function( start, end, jsEvent, view ) {
    $('#event-modal').find('input[name=evtStart]').val(
        start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    );
    $('#event-modal').find('input[name=evtEnd]').val(
        end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    );

    $('#event-modal').modal('show');

    $("#event-modal").find('form').on('submit', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'events/save',
            data: $("#event-modal").serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                // if saved, close modal
                $("#event-modal").modal('hide');

                // refetch event source, so event will be showen in calendar
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
            }
        });
    });
},
```

You can see a complete example in **[this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/o95mxuvj/1/)**. You should note:

1. You could apply a DateTimePicker plugin in the start and end inputs (such as [this](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) or [this](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) or any other that you can find on Google)
2. You need to adjust the `$.ajax` call to provide the correct URL and save the events on the database.
3. I've not tested this 100%, this is intended as a way to get you on the right track. This means that you probably have to tweak the code to fit your needs.